# Undefined method 'hasRole'.intelephense(1013)

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

```
if (auth()->check() && (auth()->user()->hasRole('Admin'))) {
    $people = Person::latest()->paginate(5);
} else {
    $people = Person::where('user_id', $user->id)->latest()->paginate(5);
}
```

My editor code analysis tool is not able to detect the method.Undefined method 'hasRole'.intelephense(1013)

The 'if' condition is working correctly.

Comment: Your code is probably working fine, it's just VSCode doesn't understand it. You may need to install a Laravel extension for code hints.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [this solution from GitHub](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1051#issuecomment-629142709):

> Because if you use Auth::user() the extension does not know it's actually a user model.

1. let independence know that we use an instance of the User model: `/** @var \App\Models\User */`;
2. define the `$user` variable as a result of `auth()->user()` or `Auth::user()`;
3. use `$user->hasRole()` in your code.

```php
/** @var \App\Models\User */
$user = auth()->user();  // or Auth::user()
if ($user->hasRole('YourRole')) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that happened because the code analysis tool you are using doesn't know that it is a `user` model. you could define the authenticated user to a variable like so

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

and then use it with hasRole like so

```
$user->hasRole('role')
```

source: https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1051#issuecomment-629142709